# Display new posts categories in separated divs

Tags: posts, categories, loop

(1) Hello smart people, this is my very first time creating a template... I made a small sketch of my goal:
[image]

I was able to do it by starting the loop before each div section and pulling the post of each specific category:

```
$params = array('posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_cat' => 'Pies', ); $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
```

But crearly that only works with specified categories, so I need it to automatically add the products of a newly created category (like cat 4 after cat 3...)

How can I accomplish this?

(2) I wish to add a "more" button at the bottom of each category div, so it shows the rest of category's posts, like this:

[image: when more is toggled]

Can this be done with wordpress? or do I create a JQuery function that increases 'posts_per_page'? I really appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You should first make a query to retrieve all your categories. This can be done using:

```
$categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty'=> 0,));
```

Now that you have a list of your categories as object, you have to run a `foreach` to output their content:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'post_type' => 'product', 
        'cat' => $category->term_id, 
    ); 
    $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
    //From here you can start outputting your query
    if ($wc_query->have_posts()) { ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $category->term_id;?>" class="product-list-grid">
        while ($wc_query->have_posts()) {
            $wc_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="product-grid">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                   <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </div><?php
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();?>
        <a class="more-products" href="#" onclick=" document.getElementById("<?php echo $category->term_id;?>").style.height = "auto";">More</a>
        </div><?php
    }
}
```

Don't forget to use `wp_reset_postdata()` when you are finished with your query.

Now let's style it, shall we?

```
.product-list-grid {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    position:relative
}

.product-grid {
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:80px;
    display:block
}

.product-grid img {
    float:left;
}

.more-products {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:10px;
   right:10px;
}
```

Now, after clicking `More` button, all your products will be visible. Remember, you have to change the number of queried products to return all available product if you want this to work.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I found a similar function in an answer of another question but I failed to adapt it to my style, it displays all products within "col"s but I would like each category to end where div "pFlex" ends, if it is not too much of a bother can you help me find where I went wrong? https://pastebin.com/39ffuVUe

Comment: @gallantsun Sure. Since the first part of your provided function is the same as mine, i just added the second part to my answer, and modified it. Please read the answer FULLY again, i changed the content.